# Restore Postgres database using pg_restore over SSH

Tags: postgresql, ssh, pg-restore

I have a database server without much disk space, so I took a backup of the entire db (let's just call it redblue) and saved it locally using the following command (I don't have pg running on my computer):

```
ssh admin@w.x.y.z "pg_dump -U postgres redblue -h localhost " \
 >> db_backup_redblue.sql
```

I'd like to now restore it to another server (1.2.3.4) which contains an older version of "redblue" database - however wanted to ask if this is right before I try it:

```
ssh admin@1.2.3.4 "pg_restore -U postgres -C redblue" \
<< db_backup_redblue.sql
```

I wasn't sure if I need to do -C with the name of the db or not?

Will the above command overwrite/restore the remote database with the file I have locally?

Thanks!

Comment: You might do better asking this on [dba.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will do nothing good.

You have to start `pg_restore` on the machine where the dump is. Actually, since this is a plain format dump, you have to use `psql` rather than `pg_restore`:

```
psql -h 1.2.3.4 -U postgres -d redblue -f db_backup_redblue.sql
```

That requires that there is already an empty database `redblue` on the target system.

If you want to replace an existing database, you have to use the `--clean` and `--create` options with `pg_dump`.

If you want to use SSL, you'll have to configure the PostgreSQL server to accept SSL connections, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html).

I'd recommend the “custom” format of `pg_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do this :) Assuming you use ssh keys to authorize user from source host to destination host.

On the source host you do the pg_dump, then pipe through ssh to destination host like this:

```
pg_dump -C nextcloud | ssh -i .ssh/pg_nextcloud_key postgres@192.168.0.54 psql -d template1
```

Hope that helps ;)